# Struggling to import openbb. Instead of that I got the message 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile, BadZipFile
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
from openbb import obb
```

Initially I got the message, `No module named 'openbb_terminal'`
So I gave up through anaconda and installed miniconda and opened the file through miniconda3 but the result is the same.
Message are as per below.
Please give me an solution who knows openbb (I just thought that is better from beginner's perspective) if possible please?

```
----> 8 from openbb_core.app.static.app_factory import (
      9     BaseApp as _BaseApp,
     10     create_app as _create_app,

---> 51 def get_major_minor(version: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
     52     """Retrieve the major and minor version from a version string."""
     53     parts = version.split(".")

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```